# create a subscription form in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm trying to create a simple Newsletter subscription form in my Zend Project (v.1.1.12)

This form will be displayed in my index.phtml.

Here's what I've done so far :
I've declared a new form called Newsletter.php in the folder application/form/

It's a simple text field with a submit button

```
class Form_Newsletter extends Zend_Form
{
 public function init()
 {
    $this->setName('newsletter_subscribe');
    $this->setMethod('post');

    $u_email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('nl_email');
    $u_email->setRequired(true)
        ->addFilter('StripTags')
        ->addFilter('StringTrim')
        ->addValidator('EmailAddress') ;


    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton2');
    $submit->setAttrib('class', 'btn');

        $this->addElements(array($u_email,$submit));
  }
}
```

Next step, in my IndexController.php (under application/Controllers), I declared my Form :

```
public function indexAction()
{   
    //$this->_helper->layout()->setLayout('simplecontent');
    $db=new Db();

    /*Newsletter*/
        $form = new Form_Newsletter();
        $form->submit->setLabel('Valider');
        $this->view->newsletter_form = $form;

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($form->isValid($formData)) {                
                $email = $form->getValue('nl_email');
                $db->runquery("insert into newsletterrecipients(email)   values(".$email.")");
            } else {
                $form->populate($formData);
            }
        }


}
```

and then i render it in my layout like that :

```
<div class="newsletter">            
        <?php echo $this->newsletter_form; ?>   
</div>
```

All i want is to insert the e-mail provided into the table named 'newsletterrecipients' but it doesn't work when i submit the form, no data is recorded.

Thanks for your precious help

Comment: Are you using `zf v.1.1` or `zf v.1.12` ??

Comment: Have you define this `Db` class yourself??

Comment: I would say your 'runquery' method might be a problem. Why not do this 'Zend Way'?

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola no, this is the standard class

Comment: @Volvox Do you mean create a new db class, for exemple Newsletterdb ?

Comment: @StéphaneJoos Yes. Create Newsletterdb class which extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`. Then just `$m = new NewsletterDb()` and `$row = $m->createRow()` -> `$row->email =  $email` and finally `$row->save()`

Comment: Yes @Volvox is right but Do you know how to do it??

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola. No, i am new to ZF. Can you indicate me the steps ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Add this lines in your `application.ini`

```
resources.db.adapter = pdo_mysql
resources.db.params.host = yourhostname
resources.db.params.username = yourusername
resources.db.params.password = yourpassword
resources.db.params.dbname = "yourdatabasename"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

**Step 2:**

Create Your db-table class by extending `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` here:

application/models/DbTable/Newsletter.php

```
<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_Newsletter extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    protected $_name = 'your database table name';
}

?>
```

**Step 3:**

Now you are able to create your dbtable object in your `controller`:

```
$newsletter = new Application_Model_DbTable_Newsletter();
$row = $newsletter->createRow();
$row->email = $email;
$row->save();
```

This might be help you.

Comment: Here is how is my application.ini file, which is different from yours :

`database.adapter       = "PDO_MYSQL"
database.params.dbname = "xxxxx"
database.params.host = "xxxxx"
database.params.username = "xxxxx"
database.params.password = "xxxxx"
database.isDefaultTableAdapter = true`

Is it important ?

Comment: If it's working than it's ok otherwise replace it with mine.

Comment: Should the db class not be named Application_Model**s**_DbTable_Newsletter, as the folder name is "models" ?

Comment: Right now it's returning me an error : Fatal error: Class 'Application_Models_DbTable_Newsletter' not found

Comment: Check out my blog you might get some help from their: https://zendframework1tutorial.wordpress.com

Comment: It's not working. I've got the error : Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_DbTable_Newsletter' not found

Comment: Do you have teamviewer??

Comment: Weird, it doesn't find the class.

To sum up, i've got now a file named newsletter.php into application/models/DBTable.

This file contains this :

`<?php

class Application_Model_DbTable_Newsletter extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    protected $_name = 'newsletterrecipients';
}


?>`

It should be Okay. 'newsletterrecipients' is the name of my table

Answer (score 0):

Create new file `Newsletter` in `Models` folder.

```
class Application_Model_Newsletter extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
protected $_name = 'newsletter'; //name of DB table
}
```

Now in `indexAction` you can use:

```
$nModel = Application_Model_Newsletter();
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {                
        $row = $nModel->createRow();
        $row->email = $form->getValue('nl_email');
        $row->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now it's returning me an error : Fatal error: Class 'Application_Model_DbTable_Newsletter' not found.

Do you have any clue ?

Comment: You need to check if its in correct folder. In mine example it should be in `application\models\Newsletter.php`, while in Indrasinh Bihola example it should be in `application\models\DbTable\Newsletter.php`. Also check if spelling is correct. Also use uppercase for first letter in filename(Newsletter.php)